# Which Haskell string type to use for Unicode data when fast (O(1)) indexing is required?

Tags: string, haskell, unicode

After reading about all 5 (`String, Text, Text.Lazy, ByteString, ByteString.Lazy`) commonly used types for strings in Haskell I am rather at the end of my wits:

What I need is a String type which is immutable (I read it once from a file and never change it), with fast indexing (O(1)) and which can be consumed by code point, rather than by potentially incomplete bytes, which form a code point.

I could live with a `Data.ByteString.UTF32`, actually, as with that representation, I would not need to be careful about multi byte encoding ever again.

Will I have to write myself such a module or - by any chance - did someone else come to the same conclusion and did it already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds just like an array of `Char`: `Data.Vector.Unbox.Vector Char`.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.3/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html

Comment: Is ``Char`` not 16 bit? With something like UTF16 there is still the code point and multi "word" issue. But I like your idea - I could go for a ``Data.Vector.Unbox.Vector Word32`` and be done with just a few conversion functions...

Comment: @BitTickler, no, `Char` is a full code point, stored as 32 bits.